# What is the definition of the "characteristic radius"?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, spacetime, curvature

Upon solving exercises regarding relativity, I have run into the problem below.

The inverse square radius of curvature of spacetime is of orer the tidal field, $R^{-2} \approx \nabla^2 \phi$ where $\phi$ is the Newtonian potential. What (approximate) conditions must be satisfied by the characteristic radius $r$ of an object of mass $M$ for the radius of curvature of spacetime to be smaller than $r$?

Here, what exactly is the characteristic radius? Could anyone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

“Characteristic radius” is a vague term. For a sphere, it is obviously the radius. For an arbitrary shape with volume $V$, you could take it to be the $R$ satisfying $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$.